# How to change order of an event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a ul and a li when you click li tags li click function active first because it's the child.
I want to when you click li ul function active first. What should I do?

```js
$("ul").click(function(){
  alert("Yeah I did it!");
 });
 
$("li").click(function(){
  alert("Noooooo!");
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Upgrade to a proper jQuery version
2. Delegate
3. execute in order on one click

```js
$("ul").on("click","li",function(){
  alert("Yeah I did it!");
  alert("Noooooo!");  
  
  console.log($(this).closest("ul").attr("id"));
  console.log($(this).index(),$(this).text());
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUl">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
</ul>
```